# What denominations use the Revised Common Lectionary?

Tags: denomination-survey, liturgy, lectionary

What denominations use the Revised Common Lectionary? And in those denominations, is there typically a copy of the RCL in the pews? Does anyone using it read from other translations or always from the NRSV that is printed in the hard copies?

Comment: Is this a list question? (And [my copy of the RCL](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0687361745) is just a table of references; there are no texts included. We used the NIV for the readings.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from the Episcopalian perspective, I can say that, a.) We use the RCL and b.) The [Book of Common Prayer](http://www.bcponline.org/) (BCP) includes a copy of the RCL references as well as a lectionary for the daily office readings. And the BCP is in the pews for sure.

As stated, a lectionary is often simply a list of scripture references. But it can certainly include the readings.

Answer (score 1):

The Lutheran Church - Missouri Synod (LCMS) uses a variation of the RCL (there's an article about it, along with the lectionary at: http://www.lcms.org/resources/worship/lectionary )

The Lutheran Service Book (LSB) used by the LCMS has the lectionary printed in the front with the Scripture references for each Sunday of the Church year, as well as for feasts and festivals.  During service, the lectionary texts are either printed in a bulletin and placed in the pews or (as in my congregation) we just use the pew Bibles.